# Dplyr row count by group excluding zeros

Tags: r, dplyr

I have the following dataset:

```
structure(list(BRAND = c("BRANDA", "BRANDA", "BRANDA", "BRANDA", 
                         "BRANDA"), VARIANT = c("VAR1", "VAR1", "VAR1", 
                                                  "VAR1", "VAR1"), Noodles = c(20L, 100L, 10L, 0L, 
                                                                                              50L), Peas = c(14L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 14L), milk = c(1710L, 468L, 
                                                                                                                                                   1020L, 585L, 1710L)), row.names = c(NA, 5L), class = "data.frame")
```

I am trying to derive the number of rows with non-zeros for each product column.  The desired output is as follows:

```
  BRAND VARIANT Noodles Peas milk
1 BRANDA    VAR1      4   2   5
```

I have tried using dplyr, but not sure how to get the count where values are not zero.  I am not sure if I should convert all ZEROS to NA, which doesnt seem very intuitive...or if I should use filter to remove zeros.

```
a <- ndf %>%  group_by(BRAND, VARIANT)  %>% summarise_all(funs(n()))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We could `group_by` `BRAND` and VARIANT use `summarise_all` if we want to find out non-zero count for all of the remaining columns.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(BRAND, VARIANT) %>%
  summarise_all(~sum(. != 0))

#   BRAND  VARIANT Noodles  Peas  milk
#   <chr>  <chr>     <int> <int> <int>
#1 BRANDA VAR1          4     2     5
```

If there are some other columns and you are interested to calculate non zero values only for specific columns we can use `summarise_at` similarly

```
df %>%
  group_by(BRAND, VARIANT) %>%
  summarise_at(vars(Noodles, Peas, milk), ~sum(. != 0))
```

---

Or with base R `aggregate`

```
aggregate(.~BRAND + VARIANT, df, function(x) sum(x != 0))
```

Answer (score 1):

We can do this with `data.table` using

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, lapply(.SD, function(x) sum(x != 0)), .(BRAND, VARIANT)]
```